# How to automatically direct users to second tab in window using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automatically click/open Tab2 in a web page whenever Tab1 loads so that Tab2 becomes the active tab. I'm not sure what needs to happen here since there is no specific URL to direct a user to, so would appreciate any assistance and feedback.

Thanks!

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:xy23" class="nav active">
  <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:tabSwitch">
    <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:tabSwitch.start" style="display: none">
      <img src="/img/loading.png" class="loadingimg">
    </span>
    <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:tabSwitch.stop"></span>
  </span>
  <a href="#" onclick="var a=function(){return confirmChange();if(window != window.top){var f = document.getElementById('xy1:primaryForm');f.action += (f.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&amp;');};};var b=function(){if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('xy1:primaryForm'),'xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:xy26,xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:xy26,tabId,739563,id,849324,ParentId,,RecordId,','');}return false};return (a()==false) ? false : b();">Tab1</a>
</div>
<div id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:xy23" class="nav">
  <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:tabSwitch">
    <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:tabSwitch.start" style="display: none">
      <img src="/img/loading.png" class="loadingimg">
    </span>
      <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:tabSwitch.stop"></span>
    </span>
    <a href="#" onclick="var a=function(){return confirmChange();if(window != window.top){var f = document.getElementById('xy1:primaryForm');f.action += (f.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&amp;');};};var b=function(){if(typeof jsfcljs == 'function'){jsfcljs(document.getElementById('xy1:primaryForm'),'xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:xy26,xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:xy26,tabId,643902,id,849324,ParentId,,RecordId,','');}return false};return (a()==false) ? false : b();">Tab2</a>
</div>
```

---------UPDATE-------------

I tried to simplify this a bit by not paying attention to all the functions inside the link and just wanted to click on the link based on the text()..

```css
.active {
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:xy23" class="nav active">
 <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:0:tabSwitch"></span>
 <a href="#">Tab1</a>
</div>
<div id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:xy23" class="nav ">
 <span id="xy1:primaryForm:xy22:1:tabSwitch"></span>
  <a href="#">Tab2</a>
</div>
```

The following jQuery sort of works, but it continues to click on Tab2 even when Tab2 is already active, so I want to get it to only click Tab2 if Tab1  has an active class:

```
var elements = $('a');
elements.each(function(index, domElement) {
  var $element = $(domElement);

  if ($element.text() === "Tab2") {
  $element.click();
  return false;
  }
});
```

Is there a better JavaScript Solution to click some text() only if it's a child of an .active class?